# Magento 2 Ajax add to cart related products

Tags: magento2, addtocart, ajax, related-products

So I've found the location to turn on ajax add to cart in the product page. I've also found where the;

> $showCart: true

Lives to enable the related products to have an **add to cart button** on them.

My question is, is there a way i can add an ajax add to cart for the related products? I've not seen it anywhere in the code. And I've looked. I thought by adding the ajax request to the product page may work, but looks like it is working off of the **form id**.

Now I know that the button for the related doesn't submit a form, it submits itself. So is there actually a way to ajax this?

```
$postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
```

This is what i posts, but does Magento have ajax built in for this, or do i need to create a custom module?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey do you got any solution for this?

Comment: No, I think I ended up writing a module to do it. Sorry to long ago to remember.

Comment: Any idea you can give me to proceed anywhere with this?
I am trying to write a custom ajax call to the same action with the same data, but it does not add the product to the cart.